# Why is the output of my solution to PlusOne (LeetCode Problem) so different from what I expect?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm just starting out on LeetCode doing some of the 'easy' problems and I'm trying to solve a problem called 'PlusOne' where you're asked to do the following:

"You are given a large integer represented as an integer array digits, where each digits[i] is the i-th digit of the integer. The digits are ordered from most significant to least significant in left-to-right order. The large integer does not contain any leading 0's.

Increment the large integer by one and return the resulting array of digits."

Below is the solution I came up with. The input is digits = [1, 2, 3].

```
static int[] PlusOne(int[] digits)
{
        
    string digitsToString = string.Join(string.Empty, digits);
    int stringToInt = Convert.ToInt32(digitsToString);

    stringToInt += 1;

    string outputString = stringToInt.ToString();

    int[] output = outputString.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();

    /* 
    Tried this as well, but just got the same result

    char[] outputCharArr = stringToInt.ToString().ToCharArray();
    int[] output = Array.ConvertAll(outputCharArr, Convert.ToInt32);
    */

    return output;
}
```

The expected output is [1, 2, 4], but what I get is [49, 50, 52]. I'm completely baffled as to why this the output I'm getting so if someone could explain it to me I'd be extremely appreciative!

Comment: [Essential resource:](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yong's answer will solve the problem you're having with your approach. Your solution will work up until a point but for very large numbers it will fail once you get out of range for a 32 bit integer.

Alternatively you can increment the digits like Yong hinted at, however you need to handle rolling over to "10" back to 0 and incrementing the previous digit, which is possibly one of the goals of the exercise.

```
public static int[] PlusOne(int[] digits)
{
    return incrementPosition(digits, digits.Length-1);
}

private static int[] incrementPosition(int[] digits, int position)
{
    if (position < 0 || position > digits.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("Position falls outside of digit length.");

    if (digits[position] < 0 || digits[position] > 9)
        throw new ArgumentException($"The digit at position {position} was out of range.");

    digits[position]++;
    if (digits[position] >= 10)
    {
        digits[position] = 0;
        if (position > 0)
            digits = incrementPosition(digits, position - 1);
        else
        {
            int[] updatedDigits = new int[digits.Length + 1];
            updatedDigits[0] = 1;
            digits.CopyTo(updatedDigits, 1);
            digits = updatedDigits;
        }
    }
    return digits;
}
```

This assumes that the array contains single-digit elements /w base-10 incrementing, and represents a positive value. There is a basic check for when a particular digit is incremented.  This code handles when a digit rolls over, including when a "full" array (I.e. 9, 9, 9) rolls over, inserting a new digit converting 999 to 1000.

Comment: You're completely right about the roll over from 999 to 1000 being on of the goals of the exercise, and your answer was extremely helpful in seeing where I was going wrong in my approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was from here:

```
string outputString = stringToInt.ToString();

int[] output = outputString.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Which you are converting a `char` to `int`.

According to [here](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/ASCII-American-Standard-Code-for-Information-Interchange#:%7E:text=ASCII%20(American%20Standard%20Code%20for%20Information%20Interchange)%20is%20the%20most,additional%20characters%20and%20control%20codes.), you will get the result of `49` when casting from a `'1'` (char) [Known as ASCII].

| char | int |
| --- | --- |
| '1' | 49 |
| '2' | 50 |
| '4' | 52 |

If your `int` array with a guarantee with orders (smallest to largest), you can just update the last value of the array as below:

```cs
static int[] PlusOne(int[] digits)
{
    digits[digits.Length - 1] += 1;
        
    return digits;
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BfJjXC)